# How to solve The wait operation timed out Error #asp.net #sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, amazon-ec2, connection-timeout

The wait operation **timed out Error** In Mvc.
when i run my application in local server it work fine ....but after deploy of Project in Server i am getting this Error ...
In my Local DataBase and Server database have same entry.
plz tell me how to solve..

Local server:
[image: local server]

Server ec2 aws:
[image: server ec2 aws]

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding a Timeout setting to the Command object worked.

```
      `myCmd.CommandTimeout = 1000`
```

You also should add a timeout setting for your connection string.

`SqlConnection("Data Source=SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=1000")`

See the [other post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176692/the-wait-operation-timed-out-asp).

Comment: Connection Timeout has nothing to do with the actual execution of the code.  Command Timeout is what you're after.