# Localhost SQL Server database is extremely slow and site times out when exporting from Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure-sql-database

I have a database on Azure that is around 500mb, ~50 tables and a few tables with 100k+ records. A single table with ~1000k records. This is not a big database (around 20-50 DTU's). I have an ASP.NET MVC application that runs on top of this database.

When I run towards this database either from local or on my test/production environment, the database is extremely fast. My code is "solid production code" (indexes, paging), meaning I do not do anything crazy and this works on pretty heavy production loads.

However, when I import this database locally, it's VERY, VERY slow (pages takes 10-20 seconds to load, or simply fails). This results in I basically cannot run my application locally. Here is an example error I get (DK error message, but the typical error - see [The wait operation timed out. ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176692/the-wait-operation-timed-out-asp) ) :

[image]

I experience the same problem when I run queries outside my main application. I am 99% sure this is a database problem, not an application problem because when I run scripts it's very slow too.

Any idea what the problem is? Why is my localhost so slow it cannot barely run normal queries?

This is how I created my local databae:

[image]

Save to local desktop:

[image]

I import into `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` :

[image]

Wait for this to happen and everything is confirmed. I then change my connection string to this database.

Comment: I would start by installing SQL Server Developer Edition, instead of trying to troubleshoot performance on SQL Express LocalDb.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Nice suggestion. I'll download over the weekend and test!

Comment: There are a couple of solutions here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4e6ba2d7-9565-438c-af97-82ba357302d5/query-runs-much-slower-when-connect-to-sql-server-locally?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Answer (score 3):

Enabling TCP/IP connections to your local server could resolve this issue.

1. Start -> Run -> mmc
2. File -> Add/Remove Snap-in...
3. SQL Server Configuration Manager -> [OK]
4. SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER -> TCP/IP=Enabled
5. Restart server.

Comment: Why would this resolve it?

Comment: Named Pipes can often have more overhead than TCP/IP due to additional context switching and synchronization, which can cause it to be slower in some scenarios.

Comment: That said, it's entirely possible that OP's problem was caused by index fragmentation and could be resolved by rebuilding statistics and optimising indexes.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you do not have enough RAM to host your own server. I had that problem, locally hosting MSSQL server 2012 with 8GB of RAM on a Windows 10 machine, with Core i7 10th Gen. Sometimes there were no problems, but mostly I was getting very slow query response times, and even timeouts. This was my development machine, and I noticed that all the RAM was being consumed, just from development alone, without any database connections. So I suspected that there was not enough memory for querying the database as well.

I increased the RAM to 32GB (but 16GB would have sufficed), and problems solved.