# The wait operation timed out. .aspx

Tags: sql, .net, runtime-error, connection-timeout, .aspxauth

I created an internal website for our company. It run smoothly for several months and then I add more items to website. When I run in live, it run normally. Then suddenly one of my user from another server sending me an "The Wait operation timed out." error. When I check access that certain link, It run normally for me and some other who I ask to check if they access that page. I already increase the connection timeout but still no luck. Is it the error come from another server? Can someone explain the possible causes?
This is how the another plant faced, every time they firstly open the website, error screen show up, but when they refresh it, they can use the website. I dont know why this happened. I need your  help.
Down below is a error detail:

1.Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
source error :An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.

2.Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this happens for a user but not for the testers implies this may occur when the system is under load; database timeouts are pretty common in database queries functioning under stress if the database has been set up "out of the box" without tuning.

I would suggest referring to
[The wait operation timed out. ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176692/the-wait-operation-timed-out-asp)

I don't have enough information to troubleshoot more question properly, since I don't know what DBMS you are working with. But as a rule this seems to happen because a call to the database is timing out. In SQL Server, increasing the CommandTimeout (NOT connection timeout) is one of the quick-and-dirty ways to solve the problem.

In SQL Server, CommandTimeout is the time allowed for an operation before exiting with a time out error. Connectiontimeout, by contrast, is the time the system waits when trying to open an initial connection to the database. Changing connectiontimeout won't help with the timeout of an operation, but commandtimeout will.

Other DBMS systems will have other mechanisms for resolving timeout issues.

That's one quick and dirty solution.  The longer solution is to add more logging to your system to identify which calls are timing out, then doing some DBA work to optimize the query and database performance.   My understanding is that entity frameworks also have tuning options for automatically generated queries, but exactly what those are depends on which one you're using!